# Why POSIX signals are ignored on some Linux machines?

Tags: ruby, linux, signals, posix

I have a few Linux machines (Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 7.5). I run exactly the same Ruby script on all of them. Then, I send `kill -CONT pid` to each of them (to get [sigdump](https://github.com/frsyuki/sigdump/) log). Some machines react, others completely ignore the signal. What could be the reason?

Cross-posted [here](https://github.com/frsyuki/sigdump/issues/10).

Comment: To the Ruby script or to some other process? It could be how Ruby is compiled. Maybe that debugging feature wasn't built into one. Each distribution has their own Ruby maintainer with different build priorities.

Answer (score -1):

One process can programmatically change a signal behaviour (except SIGKILL and SIGSTOP) 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html